# How can i get the initial context path in my custom sapui5 control?

Tags: sapui5

i have designed my own custom sapui5 control. This control is also used as a template in a 'sap.ui.table' control. This table contains 5 rows and is bound to an odata result set with mostly more than 5 rows. So when i now scroll through this table, i have to adapt my control to the new bound value. But the value of this control can also be changed due to propertybinding by an other control of the same table row because of an dependency between the values of bound data of that row.

So i have to recognize, if a value change in the control is issued by a "normal" property setting by a change method of another control in the same row, or if it is issued by a table scroll operation.

For this i check the contextpath of the bound value in the setter of my control. if the context path is different from my stored last context path, the change is issued by a table scroll operation. If the context is unchanged, it is issued by another programmatically operation (maybee the change-event of another control in the same table row which has a dependency to this control).

For this i store the context-path in an internal instance variable of my control. But the problem is the initial value. How can i save the inital, first bound context path, in my control. It is not possible and allowed to check this in the constructor of my control. And initially a scroll and and a programmtic change would return a context change.

Here a simplified code snippet of my control for better understanding. Because of the simplyfing excuse for syntax errors.

```
sap.ui.define(["sap/ui/core/Control",
    "sap/ui/model/Filter",
    "sap/ui/model/FilterOperator"   
], function (Control, Filter, FilterOperator) {
    "use strict";
    return Control.extend("MyControl", {
        "metadata": {
            "properties": {
                "value"                         : { type : "string" }
            }
        },

        init: function () {
            this._lastContextPath       = "";   // should store the last context path 
        },
        
        
        setValue : function(oValue) {
            // Setter Method for my value Property
            this.setProperty("value1",oValue);
            // Check if setter was issued by scrolling if this control 
            // is bound to a table
            if (this.getId().indexOf("clone") > 0) // Simplified recognition if control is created by template
                if ( !this._hasContextChanged() ) {
                    // Do something in the parent-control where this Control is in its aggregation
                    // because Context not changed, so Setter is issued programmtically
                    if (typeof this.getParent() !== 'undefined' && this.getParent() !== null) {
                        // In this case the Parent-Method refreshFromChild should be invoke with the 
                        // value of this control
                        this.getParent.refreshFromChild(oValue);
                    }
                }
            }   
        },

        // Checks if a context change has happend
        _hasContextChanged : function() {
            var oBinding  = this.getBinding("value");
            if ( typeof oBinding !== 'undefined' && oBinding !== null) {
                if (this.getId().indexOf("clone")>0) { // Simplified recognition if control is created by template
                    var oContext     = oBinding.getContext();
                    var sContextPath = oContext.sPath;
                    if (sContextPath !== this._lastContextPath ) {
                        // Context changed. Normally by a table scroll operation
                        this._lastContextPath = sContextPath;
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    })
)
```

Comment: There is an event for [context change](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk#/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject%23events/modelContextChange), would that help?

Comment: Unfortunatly it does not help.

Comment: Would be nice to know what you are trying to achieve. Because right now it looks like an anti-pattern.